# Rails: Turbolinks not clearing cache

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, caching, ruby-on-rails-5, turbolinks

I've got four issues.

**First case:**

In some cases I append notices and alerts to the page, those should obviously be removed from the cache. In order to do that I added the required line of JavaScript:

```
function componentsNotificationsFlashModalHide() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        if ( $('.flash-modal.flash:not(.invisible):hover').length != 0 ) {
            componentsNotificationsFlashModalHide();
        } else {
            $('.flash-modal.flash:not(.invisible)').fadeOut(250);
            Turbolinks.clearCache();
        };
    }, 4500);
};
```

Essentially, when the notification fades out, the cache should get cleared, so the next visit will fetch a new version of the page from the server.
Instead, the cached version remains as the notification does whenever coming back to the page, until I issue a full reload of the page manually.

---

**Second case:**

In my app the root template exists in two states on two separate templates and controllers depending on whether the user is signed in or not. I tried to prevent any problems by appending ...

```
%meta{ name: 'turbolinks-cache-control', content: 'no-cache' }
```

... to both document's head's.
Still, whenever a user signs in and visits the root document, the wrong version is being displayed and vice versa.

---

**Third case:**

In some cases after signing in (and getting redirected to the previous or root url) the server issues an additional redirect from the page the user lands on.

So for example a userflow could look like:

```
root_url -> login_url => root_url =!> some_other_url

-> manual
=> redirect
=!> redirect which is not working
```

That's clearly turbolinks related. After issuing a redirect manually, the server immediately redirects the user to `some_other_url`.

---

**Fourth case:**

When clicking a link with `remote: true` and `method: :put`, it appears that turbolinks responds automatically without providing a template for that specific format with:

```
Turbolinks.clearCache()
Turbolinks.visit("http://lvh.me:3000/", {"action":"replace"})
```

But instead of reloading the page and adjusting it for any new changes, it fetches the cached version which in this case cannot be intended.

---

*Rails version: 5.1.0.rc2*

Comment: This is certainly not helpful for your case, but i removed turbolinks (since its release into Rails) from every single project because it was reliably creating far more issues than benefits. Those were just my 2 cents reading the issues you're having with turbolinks.

Comment: may be this will help you: https://github.com/gemgento/rails_script/wiki/Turbolinks-Page-Transitions. I tried to fix the issue here. https://github.com/kenny-hibino/stories/pull/45/files/b204f72a6ef02358af52edf5eb10d7f0b2328069

Comment: I think at least case 1 could have to do with this: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks/issues/87. Apparently `clearCache` is async and you're not guaranteed that it's done before the next line is executed.